# UIView how to draw camera selector

Tags: ios, uiview, draw

I am searching the way to draw such frames around the view.
Is it possible to do with iOS native drawing?
[image]

Comment: You can either use a .png with such border, and transparent area. Or use bezier path to draw such paths on a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing this is easily doable with native rendering. One of ways is to create a new view and override `draw rect` method. You can do something like the following:

```
class ViewWithFrame: UIView {

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var lineThickness: CGFloat = 5 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    var lineLength: CGFloat = 30.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override var frame: CGRect { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        var paths: [UIBezierPath] = [UIBezierPath]()

        // Top left
        paths.append({
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineLength, y: 0.0))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: lineLength-lineThickness, y: lineThickness), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: lineLength, y: lineThickness))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineThickness, y: lineThickness))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lineThickness, y: lineLength-lineThickness))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: lineLength), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: lineThickness, y: lineLength))
            path.close()
            return path
            }())

        // Top right
        paths.append({
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: 0.0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width-lineLength, y: 0.0))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width-(lineLength-lineThickness), y: lineThickness), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.width-lineLength, y: lineThickness))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width-lineThickness, y: lineThickness))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width-lineThickness, y: lineLength-lineThickness))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: lineLength), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.width-lineThickness, y: lineLength))
            path.close()
            return path
            }())

        // TODO: add 2 bottom paths

        color.setFill()
        paths.forEach { $0.fill() }
    }

}
```

The bottom parts still need to be drawn but I hope you get the idea how.

Note all the calls to `setNeedsDisplay`. This is what will trigger the `draw rect` method in the next run loop and it should do so for every change of the view that can effect the drawing which also include view size.